# How do I implement this Javascript differently?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I purchased this Javascript app and it is causing me alot of issues with any javascript functionality that is after it.

I don't know javascript very well.  Is there any other way that I can write/run this script so that it doesn't affect all my other JS on the page? I don't understand JS very well.

Any JS after this code is giving me this error: TypeError: $ is not a function

Script:

```
var hap_players = [];   

        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {



            /* SETTINGS */

            var rvp_settings = {

                /* mediaId: unique string for player identification (if multiple player instances were used, then strings need to be different!) */

                mediaId:'player1',

                /* useDeeplink: true, false */

                useDeeplink:false,

                /*activePlaylist: Active playlist to start with. If no deeplink is used, enter element 'id' attribute, or if deeplink is used enter (data-address) deeplink string like 'playlist1'.  */

                activePlaylist:'playlist2',

                /*activeItem: Active video to start with. Enter number, -1 = no video loaded, 0 = first video, 1 = second video etc */

                activeItem:0,

                /* GENERAL SETTINGS */

                /*defaultVolume: 0-1 */

                defaultVolume:0.5,

                /*autoPlay: true/false (defaults to false on mobile)*/

                autoPlay:false,

                /*randomPlay: true/false */

                randomPlay:false,

                /* loopingOn: on playlist end rewind to beginning (last item in playlist) */

                loopingOn: true,

                /*autoAdvanceToNextVideo: true/false (use this to loop video) */

                autoAdvanceToNextVideo:true,

                /*autoOpenDescription: true/false  */

                autoOpenDescription:false,

                usePlaylist:true,

                useControls:true,

                /*autoHideControls: auto hide player controls on mouse out: true/false. Defaults to false on mobile. */

                autoHideControls:false,

                /*controlsTimeout: time after which controls and playlist hides in fullscreen if screen is inactive, in miliseconds. */

                controlsTimeout:3000,

                /*playlistOrientation: vertical/horizontal  */

                playlistOrientation:'horizontal',

                /*scrollType: scroll/buttons  */

                scrollType:'buttons',



                /* YOUTUBE SETTINGS */

                ytAppId:'AISyBtJyKdfdqgmhMuR9uqhj14gm89r-y9IP6CnE',/* youtube api key: https://developers.google.com/youtube/registering_an_application */

                ytTheme:'dark',

                ytShowinfo:true,



                /*playlistList: dom element which holds list of playlists */

                playlistList:'#playlist_list',



                /* showControlsInAdvert: true/false (show controls while video advert plays)  */

                showControlsInAdvert:true,

                /* disableSeekbarInAdvert: true/false (disable seekbar while video advert plays)  */

                disableSeekbarInAdvert:true,

                /* showSkipButtonInAdvert: true/false (show skip button while video advert plays)  */

                showSkipButtonInAdvert:true,

                advertSkipBtnText:'SKIP AD >',

                advertSkipVideoText:'You can skip to video in',



                logoPath: 'http://www.interactivepixel.net/images/jqueryPreviews/helper/apvplp_logo.png',

                logoPosition: '',/* tl, tr, bl, br */

                logoXOffset: 5,

                logoYOffset: 5,

                logoUrl: 'http://www.google.com',

                logoTarget: '_blank',



                useShare: false,

                /*fsAppId: facebook application id (if you use facebook share, https://developers.facebook.com/apps) */

                fsAppId:''



            };



            hap_players[0] = $('#mainWrapper').aprvp(rvp_settings);



        });
```

Comment: The code you posted appears to require jQuery. Have you included jQuery in your page?

Comment: You bought this. Have you asked the authors?

Comment: Yes.  I have jquery at the top of the page before everything.  Yes, I have consulted the author.  He can't figure out the error either.  Been working on this problem for a few days now.

Answer (score 0):

What order do you include the scripts in? It looks like this video player is dependent on jQuery, so jQuery has to be defined before any of the js files for the player.

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.address.js"></script><!-- deeplink -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mousewheel.min.js"></script><!-- scroll -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.jscrollpane.min.js"></script><!-- scroll -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/froogaloop.js"></script><!-- vimeo -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.dotdotdot-1.5.1.js"></script><!-- description shortener -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.aprvp.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
```

Comment: Hi Dan. Thanks for the reply.   The aprvp is this functionality:  http://www.interactivepixel.net/ccVideoPlayer/js/jquery.aprvp.min.js

Comment: @aerosport. Well that code is minified so it's very hard to decipher. What exactly does your application do?

Comment: it is a video player.  Here is the example page for the player.  The player works fine on its own but just messes up all the other JS on my page.  http://www.interactivepixel.net/ccVideoPlayer/index_buttons2.html

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem -- it results from the aprvp script declaring `$=jQuery.noConflict();` in the very beginning of the un-minified version.  After two days of troubleshooting, I found that you can either replace all later instances of `$` in your javascript with `jQuery` (which was too time-consuming for me) or I took the risk and just removed that line from the aprvp script and re-minified it myself.  So far, that seems to have no negative impact on anything.

Hope this helps!